# Custom directive don't want scope in this how can i achieve?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
function contentValidator() {
        var _matchContent = {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                contentValidator: '='
            },
            link: contentValidatorFn
        };
        return _matchContent;
    function contentValidatorFn(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
            var combined;
            if (scope.contentValidator || ctrl.$viewValue) {
               combined = scope.contentValidator + '_' + ctrl.$viewValue; 
            }
            return combined;
        }, function(value) {
            if (value) {
                var origin = scope.contentValidator;
                if (origin !== ctrl.$viewValue) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("contentValidator", false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("contentValidator", true);
                    return ctrl.$viewValue;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking..please update question with more details.

Comment: i am using scope like scope.contenValidator i don't want to use scope in it so what more i can use apart from it

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do use `$validators` pipeline to set validity of field of form.

```
ngModel.$validators.contentValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    var value = modelValue || viewValue;
    return condition ? value : undefined; //condition would be what you wanted to check
};
```

Basically when you return defined value from `$validators` contentValidator function, but when you don't return angular will add `content-validator` class on that fields & the same property gets added to that form field like `myForm.formFields.$error.contentValidator = true`

Comment: and what should i use for the below scope:-                                    function contentValidator() {
        var _matchContent = {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                contentValidator: '='
            },
            link: contentValidatorFn
        };

Comment: You shouldn't be passing that.

Comment: actually this directive is for matching two values, comparing so do you think it will work should i try using your changes like this: ngModel.$validators.contentValidator

Comment: @RohitGayattri so then that should pass by that way only..but why you don't wanted to pass the value to directive?

Comment: actually client wants dont use scope variables here is the fiddle please check it once where we can make changes accordingly:- https://jsfiddle.net/Ls2jh84c/

Comment: @RohitGayattri if you wanted to stick with `isolated scope` & wanted to pass `someValue` to directive then..it should be like that only.. 

one question! the value which you wanted to pass to directive, will it be dynamic/hardcoded?

Comment: yes it will be dynamic, see we click to forgot password and then for reset password we need to give email ids to both the input box for  input email whatever i type and then confirm email both the value should be same.

Comment: @RohitGayattri oh..got it..then why don't you have `emailid` & `confirm-email-id` field in a same directive, so that you don't need to pass any value to it. and directive will be called as `confirm-email` (something like that)

Comment: i didn't get your last point how we have emailid & confirm-email-id because the same directive we are using it for password and confirm password too. can you please explain me how we can do it.

Comment: @RohitGayattri provide me a fiddle with what you are trying, I'll try to figure that out in my spare time.